# Customizing MSI installer

Tags: windows, maven, wix, javafx-2

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm:

> To add a custom UI to the MSI package, you can customize WiX template file used by JavaFX
>   Packager using technique from 6.2.4. Consult WiX documentation for more details.

Assuming I figure out how to create a custom template file, how do I pass it into the JavaFX Maven Plugin?

Comment: I think the JavaFX documentation is incomplete or is missing the fact that you need to specify the plugin DLL on the commandline. This is getting closer to the solution, but requires another ant task: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22877814/296509

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add "-ext WixUIExtension " to ant script in Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595490/how-to-add-ext-wixuiextension-to-ant-script-in-netbeans)

Comment: Yes, I think they're basically duplicate questions, except that in the other question NetBeans is thrown into the mix, which is a red herring. This is a problem with the design of the JavaFX packager, requiring you to basically hack in the functionality outside the Oracle provided Ant tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When native package is created with the help of javafx-maven-plugin(2.0) we have to mention the icon for application in main/deploy/package/windows/demo.ico then the icon present in the deploy directory added to classpath like that if wix template is added in deploy directory then it might be possible that the wix template is available at classpath.

Then this wix script may be use by javafxpackager like the icon is use.ultimately the javafx plugin uses the javafxpackager internally.

Comment: have you soloution for this

Comment: the icon-file has to have a special filename: `{finalName}.ico` as documented here http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-mojo.html (scroll down to "Optional Parameters", its documented with the "deployDir"-parameter)

Comment: after becoming one of the contributers, i documented this inside issue-report: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/89#issuecomment-97534100