# How to add "-ext WixUIExtension " to ant script in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, self-contained

This is *output* of my native build script in `JavaFX`, `Netbeans IDE`.

This is *default* build via Netbeans.

```
Running [light, -nologo, -spdb, -sice:60, 
C:\Users\Firma\AppData\Local\Temp\build7911949220829827228.fxbundler\tmp\Client.wixobj, **-ext, WixUtilExtension**, -out, 
C:\devjava\rms\client\src\trunk\Client\dist\bundles\Client-2.0.msi] in 
C:\Users\Firma\AppData\Local\Temp\build7911949220829827228.fxbundler\images\win-msi\Client
```

I'm trying to **customize Wix UI interface**, that is way I need to use `WixUIExtension`.

How can I add  `"-ext WixUIExtension "` to my building process in NB.

*I do not know if this is customizable in NB.*

Comment: Have you any success or workaround for this issue. i am facing same issue. kindly help me if are

Comment: by the way this is not specific to Netbeans . i am using maven and ant-plugin and i also customized the template file but i need to provide "-ext  WixUIExtention".

Answer (score 2):

It is tricky. I think that they're still ironing out the kinks when it comes to native packaging in Netbeans 8. However, if you're using the standard JavaFX ANT tasks then just package the image when calling `<fx:deploy>`. After that you'll want to call WIX ANT tasks. These can be downloaded at http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/bindownload.cgi

Once you add *ant-dotnet-1.1.jar* to your ANT classpath then you'll be able to call WIX with the UI extension like so...

```
<wix mode="candle" source="package/windows/<YOUR_PROJECT>.WSX" wixobjdestdir="${dist.dir}/bundles"/>
<wix mode="light" source="${dist.dir}/bundles/YOUR_PROJECT.wixobj" target="${dist.dir}/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.msi">
  <lightarg line="-ext WixUIExtension"/>
</wix>
```

Comment: You say "just package the image". if i am not wrong you mean in <fx:deploy> we should just mention nativeBundles="image" instead of nativeBundles="all" ? am I correct